# Is there a way to filter multiple related fields in a single filter for a table in python Dash?

Tags: python, plotly-dash

In Microsoft PowerBI I can filter multiple related fields in a single slicer. You do so by building what's called a [hierarchy slicer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/create-reports/power-bi-slicer-hierarchy-multiple-fields). This slicer can then be used to filter a table. Can something like this be done with Python Dash?

[image]

We have an org hierarchy that we use to filter a table in a Dash application. It is a 4 tiered hierarchy. Up until now, we have used 4 successive, multi-select dropdown lists with each tier filtering the dropdown below it, but we have received feedback from users that the Power BI hierarchical slicers are much more intuitive, and they would like for us to find a similar solution, if possible.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can combine `Accordition` from `dash_mantine_components` and `Checklist` from`dash_bootstrap_components` to make something like that. Below is my sample code:

```
from dash import Dash, dash_table
import pandas as pd
import dash_mantine_components as dmc
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc
from dash.dependencies import Input ,Output
df = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/hoatranobita/holiday_challenge/main/solar.csv')

app = Dash(__name__, external_stylesheets=[dbc.themes.LUX])

app.layout = dbc.Container([
    dbc.Row([
        dbc.Col([
            dmc.Accordion(
                children=[
                    dmc.AccordionItem([
                        dmc.AccordionControl("State"),
                        dmc.AccordionPanel([
                            dbc.Checklist(
                                options=[{"label": x, "value": x} for x in df['State'].unique()],
                                value=[],
                                id="checklist-input"),
                            html.Div(id='city')]),
                    ],
                        value="customization",
                    ),
                ]),
        ],width=2),
        dbc.Col([
            dash_table.DataTable(df.to_dict('records'), 
                                 columns = [{"name": i, "id": i} for i in df.columns],
                                 id='tbl')
        ],width=10)
    ], className='p-2 align-items-center')
],fluid=True)

@app.callback(Output('city','children'),
              Input('checklist-input','value'))

def update_table(checklist):
    if checklist:
        dff = df[df['State'].isin(checklist)]
        return dmc.Accordion(
            children=[
                dmc.AccordionItem([
                    dmc.AccordionControl("City"),
                    dmc.AccordionPanel([
                        dbc.Checklist(
                            options=[
                                {"label": x, "value": x} for x in dff['City'].unique()
                            ],
                            value=[],
                            id="checklist-input-2")
                    ])
                ],
            value="customization2")
            ])


@app.callback(Output('tbl','data'),
              [Input('checklist-input','value'),
               Input('checklist-input-2','value')],
             )

def update_table(checklist, checklist2):
    if checklist != [] and checklist2 != []:
        dff = df[df['State'].isin(checklist)]
        dff = dff[dff['City'].isin(checklist2)]
        return dff.to_dict(orient='records')
    elif checklist != [] and checklist2 == []:
        dff = df[df['State'].isin(checklist)]
        return dff.to_dict(orient='records')   
    else:
        return df.to_dict(orient='records')
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=False)
```

[image]

I think it's not 100% same with your request but you can consider to use it.

Comment: Thank you for explaining how to use a checklist to filter a table. This is good. Is it possible to also create sub-tiered checkboxes, as in the image I provided? For example, in your case, under California, you might find the sub-tiered checkboxes of "San Diego", "Los Angeles", "San Francisco", etc.